# Get all anchor elements with jQuery from console?

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, firebug

I'm trying to execute some changes on ALL anchor tags. Unfortunately, things aren't going as planned.

```
$('a').remove()
```

This line only seems to affect the first element it encounters--- if I execute it in the console repeatedly, it progresses through the page removing each new anchor it finds.

I want to remove them all at once. I had thought this select would affect them all. So then I tried:

```
$('a').each(function(){this.remove();});
```

And got:

```
TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'each'
```

What is the correct solution to this, to execute code on all anchors?

Comment: @Jack - You should also add Firefox then. It applies to Firebug too.

Comment: @JosephSilber Because you ran out of rep? :)

Comment: I love how you're both using @calls when you're the only people in the conversation and the comment would notify the other automatically anyway.

Comment: @Jack - You've got more ;)

Comment: @Aerovistae Explicit > implicit :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you haven't loaded jQuery correctly.

[The console maps `$` to `document.querySelecor`](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console#selecting_elements), which only finds the first item.

---

BTW, the console also maps `$$` to `document.querySelectorAll`, so the following would work:

```
var allAnchors = $$('a');
```

You obviously won't have jQuery's methods available to `allAnchors`.

Comment: You are quite right. For some reason I assumed that the chrome console would have it built in....silly...

Comment: Man, whose crazy idea was that :)

Comment: @Jack - [I think Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API#.24.28selector.29). Though I'm not sure who copied whom.

Comment: Back in the olden days, Firebug copied Prototype.js and came up with $=document.getElementById, $$=document.querySelectorAll; Chrome's inspector copied that when it first appeared. More recently $ changed to document.querySelector in all devtools, at Paul Irish's suggestion.

Comment: So what is the code to remove all elements after all?